# C++ Pointer Defererence Declaration Syntax

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, operators, declaration

Incredibly new to C++, and have a (probably fairly dumb) question:

I've seen the `**` operator (which I understand is dereferencing a dereference) used in both contexts:

`char **arglist`

`char** arglist`

Is there a meaningful difference between the syntaxes, or are they both accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: Same exact thing.

Comment: That looks like a declaration. A declaration that says that`arglist` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.

Comment: ... in both cases.

Comment: The `*` symbol is used for several different things. In your case it is not being used as a *dereferencing* operator, it is being used to declare a *pointer type*. The same symbol `*` can then be used on such a *pointer type* to *dereference* it. So: `int* p;` declares `p` an *int pointer* but `int i = *p;` **dereferences** p to extract the `int` that it points to.

Comment: Oh @Galik is right, there was such a thing but someone edited it out?!?!, I will rollback.

Comment: `**` is not an operator. It's **two** operators, a `*` and a `*`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are exactly the same. But they are not "dereferencing a dereference" in this case, they define a *pointer to pointer to `char`*.

---

I personally prefer `char** arglist` because the `**` is like a part of the type and it's like:

```
type var_name; // where `type` is `char**` and `var_name` is arglist
```

BUT, on the other side, it may be misleading, because the following:

```
char** arglist1, arglist2;
```

defines `char**` variable named `arglist1`, AND a `char` variable named `arglist2`.

So, in order to define 2 variables with type `char**`, you need

```
char **arglist1, **arglist2;
```

or

```
char** arglist1, **arglist2;
```

or, of cource:

```
char**arglist1, **arglist2;
```

all three are the same, it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I personally prefer that too, +1 for Kiril having the potential of being a good colleague, I guess! :)

Comment: Declaring lists of variables is more a `C` legacy thing so it is not something you should really see in `C++` code. In `C++` it has always been encouraged to declare variable at the point of use. Traditionally in `C` all the declarations had to go at the top of the function - hence the long lists of declarations.

Answer (score 4):

They are the same thing, it's just style.

You can even do

```
char ** arglist
```

The white space gets stripped during run-time. I personally prefer `char** arglist` because it helps me better visualize what the object is.

Answer (score 3):

> .. are they both accomplishing the same thing?

**YES**.

---

This:

```
char **arglist;
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
char** arglist;
```

It's a type of syntax, choose one approach and *stick* to it, so that your code looks homogeneous.

Notice that in your case `**` is not being used as a dereferencing operator, it is being used to declare a pointer type, as Galik [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39624880/2411320).

Also notice that `**` consists of two star operators. In other words there is not such thing as a `**` operator.

As a final remark, I also prefer: `char** arglist;`, since it partitions the type of the variable, from the name of the variable.

---

As Kamil mentioned, this:

```
char**arglist;
```

would be equivalent, but please do *not* do this, it affects readability!

Comment: And, just for fun, `char* *arglist` is also exactly the same.

Comment: @PeteBecker thank you for the upvote! Sure they are, and for sure, people should be encouraged to use that *just for fun*! :)

Comment: Re: "`char** arglist;`, since it partitions the type of the variable" -- with the caution, of course, that the partition is visual, not syntactic. `char* x, y;` defines `y` as `char`, not `char*`.

Comment: Correct @PeteBecker!

Answer (score 3):

Both syntaxes are identical. But neither one is *dereferencing* in your examples.

The `*` symbol is used for several different things. In your case it is not being used as a *dereferencing* operator, it is being used to declare a *pointer type*. The same symbol `*` can then be used on such a *pointer type* to *dereference* it. So: `int* p;` declares `p` to be of compound type *int pointer* but `int i = *p;` **dereferences** p to extract the `int` that it points to.

Comment: Bravo for catching that, even though it was wrongly discarded from OP's post from another user.

Answer (score 2):

There are no diffrences .`char**arglist` is as good as others.

Comment: Yeah, but my keyboard has the space key! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference whatsover. It depends on the programmer, some prefer `char* ptr;` and some `char *ptr;`.

The same goes for any qualifier that can be added to the type:

- `const int a = 0;` and `int const a = 0;`
- `const int& a = b;` and `int const& a = b;`
- `int &&a = 0;` and `int && a = 0;`

They all mean the same thing in each case.